# How to make an user-select effect when hover an image

Tags: html, css

When you select an image on web browser, the image become blue. If I want it become blue on hover, what should I do? I tried to have an overlapping div with blue background and opacity:0, then its opacity become 0.65 when hover, but I have no idea why the effect ran so slowly.

Here is a jsfiddle of what I tried to do: jsfiddle.net/hq5b2/1/

Comment: Your fiddle runs fine for me and the hover effect seems perfectly normal speed in both Chrome 33 and IE 11... Calculating opacity and overlapping elements are some of the more processor-intensive things that you can do with HTML/CSS, but still, I wouldn't expect the sample as small as in that fiddle to be noticeably slow for the vast majority of users.

Comment: I'm using FireFox and I think my computer is fine >.> At first, when I hover on it, it turns blue immediately, but when I move the cursor, it takes a while to turns back to normal, not much, but noticeable.